# Как протестировать функцию в JUnit?

Tags: java, javafx

нужно протестировать функцию String coding() в JUnit:
- убедится в том, что функция не возвращает null.
    И что она возвращает строку длинна которой больше единицы

```
  import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.String;

/**
 * Класс Программист
 */

    введите сюда код

class Programmer extends Human {
    /** Число, используемое для рандомного количества символов*/
    private static final int RAND_SIZE = 150;
    /** Минимальное количество символов*/
    private final int MIN_RAND = 50;
    /** Алфавит, используемый при создании Программистом кода*/
    private final String alphabet = ("QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890(){}[]<>=!,");

/**
     * Конструктор по умолчанию
     */
    Programmer() {
        super ();
    }
    /**
     * Конструктор с параметрами
     * @param name имя
     */
    Programmer (String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    /**
     * @return набор символов, являющийся "кодом", написанным Программистом
     */
    String coding(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int size = rand.nextInt(RAND_SIZE) + MIN_RAND;
        String code = "";
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            char a = alphabet.charAt(rand.nextInt(alphabet.length()));
            code+=a;
        }
        return code;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class ProgrammerTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnNonNullValue() {
        Programmer programmer = new Programmer();

        assertNotNull(programmer.coding());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnStringWithLengthMoreThanOne() {
        Programmer programmer = new Programmer();

        assertTrue(programmer.coding().length() > 1);
    }
}
```

Разумеется, нужно подключить jUnit библиотеку